# Password is not being accepted

Tags: login, login-screen

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed in my PC. It was working just fine but now, at the time of login, when I enter my password, Screen goes blank and again the login page is displayed. However if password is incorrect, message is prompted. What could be done in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 1):

When this happens to me, it is usually because I have added an error into my `~/.bashrc`.

For me the solution usually goes like this:

1. Hit Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get to console
2. Log in there
3. Open the file ~/.xsession-errors in your favourite editor:

   ```
   nano ~/.xsession-errors
   ```
4. Go to the bottom and see what was the last error that made the login fail.
5. Now edit `~/.bashrc` or whatever file is causing the error, and fix it.
6. Ctrl-Alt-F7 or F8 to get back to the graphical login screen, and try to log in again!